# Automatically hide a div using jQuery if it gets no MouseOver in a time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a workaround that shows a div when a menu item gets MouseOver, but hides both only when the div gets MouseOut.  This is required for now.

However, if the div never gets MouseOver, it never hides.  What I would like to do is automatically hide the div if it doesn't get MouseOver within a few milliseconds of showing.

The hiding after a time shouldn't be hard, but reseting this on a MouseOver challenges me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like:

```
function hideYourDiv() {
  $("div#yourdiv").hide();
}
var theTimeout = setTimeout(hideYourDiv, 1000);
$("div#yourdiv").mouseover(function() {
  clearTimeout(theTimeout);
});
```

**edited** to conform to "proper" use of setTimeout :P (though for simple stuff like this I sometimes prefer to pass it a string.. both work anyway)

Comment: +1 for `clearTimeout` but -1 for passing a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: setTimeout takes a string parameter, although it would be a little cleaner to just put a function call in that string and put the jQ code in that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout() to set a timeout, but you can also use clearTimeout. Each time you get a mouseOver, you can clear the previous timeOut and set a new one.